# How to move a text in html/css

Tags: html, css

Hy guys, I would like to know how can I solver this problem.
As you can see in the image bellow the text is stuck to the left side.

[image]

Here the **HTML** code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> PROJETO HARDWELL - História </title>

    <meta name="author" content="João Santos">

    <meta name="description" content="Aqui descrevo a minha página">

    <meta name="keywords" content="HARDWELL ">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="//cdn.djhardwell.com/assets/core/img/favicon.png">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="assets/css/historia.css" rel="stylesheet">




</head>



<body>


    <!-----------------------------VIDEO E TEXTO------------------------------------->

    <div style="max-width:1280px;margin:0 auto; padding:5px; ">
        <div style="position: relative;padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden;">
            <iframe width="1280" height="720" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" autoplay
                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WSYWLB3QKik?autoplay=1&mute=1" scrolling="no"
                style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; max-width: 1280px; max-height: 720px;"
                tabindex="-1"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>


    <section>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Hardwell (nascido como Robbert van de Corput em Breda, Holanda) é um produtor progressivo de electro
                house DJ. Em 2009 , após o sucesso de “Show Me Love vs.Be”, ele começou a produzir várias outras track
                “singles” de sucesso na EDM como “Encoded” e “Cobra” e também começou a forma grandes parcerias como o
                seu ídolo de infância DJ Tiesto e entre outros nomes da musica eletrônica.
                <br>Em 2010 ele formou a sua própria produtora a Revelad Recordings e em 2011 foi classificado em número
                24 no Top DJ Mag.
                <br>Ao lado de outros artistas como Alesso, Koyu Deniz e R3hab, Hardwell foi nomeado para artista do ano
                em 2012 pela MTV.
                <br>Em Novembro participou do Dreamvalley Festival em Santa Catarina e também neste mês tornou-se o #6
                no Top Dj Mag do mundo pela revista DjMag.
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <h1 style="color:white;">Lista de remixes:</h1>
                <br>
                <!---->
                <h2 style="color:white;">2003</h2>
                <br>
                <p style="color:white;font-size:19px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;.The Underdog Project vs. Sunclub – "Summer
                    Jam 2003" (DJ Hardwell Bubbling Mix) </p>
                <br>
                <p style="color:white;font-size:19px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;.DHS – "House of God" (DJ Hardwell Mix) </p>
                <br>
                <p style="color:white;font-size:19px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;.Da Klubb Kings – "Two Thumbs Up" (DJ
                    Hardwell Mix) </p>
                <br>
                <p style="color:white;font-size:19px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;.Ruthless & Vorwerk – "I Feel Like Dancing"
                    (DJ Hardwell Mix) </p>
                <br>
                <p style="color:white;font-size:19px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;.Rmxcrw – "Turn Me On" (DJ Hardwell Mix) </p>
                <br>
                <p style="color:white;font-size:19px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;.Camisra – "Let Me Show You" (DJ Hardwell
                    Mix) </p>
                <br>
                <p style="color:white;font-size:19px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;.Praise Cats – "Shined On Me" (DJ Hardwell
                    Mix) </p>
                <br>
                <!---->
                <br>
                <h2 style="color:white;">2008</h2>
                <br>
                <p style="color:white;font-size:19px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;.EliZe – "Hot Stuff" (Hardwell Sunrise Mix)
                </p>
                <br>
                <p style="color:white;font-size:19px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;.Gregor Salto – "Bouncing Harbour" (Hardwell
                    & R3hab Remix) </p>
                <br>
                <p style="color:white;font-size:19px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;.Laidback Luke – "Break Down the House"
                    (Hardwell & R3hab Remix) </p>
                <br>
                <p style="color:white;font-size:19px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;.The Partysquad – "Stuk" </p>
                <br>
                <p style="color:white;font-size:19px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;.Robbie Taylor & Marc MacRowland – "Black
                    Bamboo" </p>
                <br>
                <p style="color:white;font-size:19px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;.Booty Luv – "Dance Dance" </p>
                <br>
                <p style="color:white;font-size:19px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;.DJ Chuckie - "Drop Low" </p>
                <br>
                <!---->
                <br>
                <h2 style="color:white;">2015</h2>
                <br>
                <p style="color:white;font-size:19px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;.Domeno & Michael Sparks - Locked & Loaded
                    (Hardwell Edit) </p>
                <br>
                <p style="color:white;font-size:19px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;.Calvin Harris feat. Ellie Goulding - Outside
                    (Hardwell Remix) </p>
                <br>
                <p style="color:white;font-size:19px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;.Quintino - Scorpion (Hardwell Edit) </p>
                <!---->
                <br>
                <h2 style="color:white;">2016</h2>
                <br>
                <p style="color:white;font-size:19px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;.Alan Walker feat. Iselin Solheim – "Faded"
                    (Hardwell Remix) </p>
                <br>
                <p style="color:white;font-size:19px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;.The Chainsmokers feat. Daya – "Don't Let Me
                    Down" (Hardwell & Sephyx Remix) </p>
                <br>
                <p style="color:white;font-size:19px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;.Moby – "Go" (Hardwell Remix) </p>
                <!---->
                <br>
                <h2 style="color:white;">2017</h2>
                <br>
                <p style="color:white;font-size:19px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;.Kill The Buzz – "Break The House Down"
                    (Hardwell Edit) </p>
                <br>
                <p style="color:white;font-size:19px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;.TBadd Dimes – "Go Down Low" (Hardwell Edit)
                </p>

        </div>

    </section>
    <!-----------------------------VIDEO E TEXTO------------------------------------->



</body>

</html>
```

Here the **CSS** code:

```html
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10;
    font-family: Century Gothic;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}






/*---------------------VIDEO-------------------*/
section {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 100px;
}

section video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    pointer-events: none;
}


section p {
    top: 80%;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

/*---------------------VIDEO-------------------*/



/*------------------TEXTO-----------------------*/
.content{
    color:white;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:Century Gothic;
}
/*------------------TEXTO-----------------------*/
```

I wanted to know how can I move it please.

Comment: Use margin and padding, they are there for a reason!

Comment: Could you check your image link to make it work please and also make your code into one snippet which we can run and also explain what you want it to look like.

Comment: and please combine CSS and HTML into one snippet.

Comment: this *fggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggh* is unnecessary btw. You can use margin and padding to move the text